# How do you move files from one folder to the other?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to move specific files from one folder to another. Would the below work?

```
mkdir test

touch test1.sh
touch test2.sh
touch test3.sh

mkdir test2

find test/ | xargs -I% mv % test2
```

Comment: You didn't put any of the `textX.sh` files in `test`.

Comment: Try `touch test/test{1,2,3}.sh`

Comment: But the `find` command should work.

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can work:

```
find ./ -name "test*.sh" | xargs -I% mv % test2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is somethin odd in your example:

If *test1* does **not** contain any subdirectories, or if you want to move the subdirectories as they are, you could simply do a

```
mv test1/* test2
```

(Note that this would (by default) not move entries which start with a period. If this is a problem, you either should consider not using Posix shell but, say, bash or Zsh, or indeed could use `find`, for the safe side with the `-prune` option) .

The problem starts with subdirectories. The output of find contains all directories along with the files at the end. The `mv` inside the `xargs` would then move, say, a directory test1/foo, and if it later wants to process a file test1/foo/bar/baz.txt, the file is not here anymore. The overall effect would be that you would have moved all the subdirectory (as in my first solution which does not need `find`), but get in addition plenty of error messages.